# How to generalize std::chrono::duration(s)?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++-chrono

I wrote three versions of algorithm for my university class.

One is brute-force, other is greedy and the last is heuristic.

I want to be able to measure how much time each of the algorithms takes to complete.

I'm using `<chrono>` library to achieve this

Right now my code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string getTimeElapsed(long time1, const string &unit1, long time2 = 0, const string &unit2 = "") {
    stringstream s;
    s << time1 << " [" << unit1 << "]";
    if (time2) s << " " << time2 << " [" << unit2 << "]";
    return s.str();
}

int main() {
    auto begin = chrono::system_clock::now();
    // algorithm goes here
    auto solution = /* can be anything */
    auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto diff = end - begin;

    string timeElapsed;
    auto hours = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::hours>(diff).count();
    auto minutes = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::minutes>(diff).count();
    if (hours) {
        minutes %= 60;
        timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(hours, "h", minutes, "min");
    } else {
        auto seconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(diff).count();
        if (minutes) {
            seconds %= 60;
            timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(minutes, "min", seconds, "s");
        } else {
            auto milliseconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(diff).count();
            if (seconds) {
                milliseconds %= 1000;
                timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(seconds, "s", milliseconds, "ms");
            } else {
                auto microseconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(diff).count();
                if (milliseconds) {
                    microseconds %= 1000;
                    timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(milliseconds, "ms", microseconds, "μs");
                } else {
                    auto nanoseconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(diff).count();
                    if (microseconds) {
                        nanoseconds %= 1000;
                        timeElapsed = timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(microseconds, "μs", nanoseconds, "ns");
                    } else timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(nanoseconds, "ns");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Solution [" << solution << "] found in " << timeElapsed << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the stacked `if-else` clauses look really ugly and you can see a pattern here:

```cpp
if (timeUnit) { 
    timeElapsed = /* process current time units */
} else {
    /* step down a level and do the same for smaller time units */
}
```

I would like to make that procedure a recursive function.

However, I have no clue what should be the parameters of such function, because the `chrono::duration` is a template struct (?)

This function would look somewhat like this :

```cpp
string prettyTimeElapsed(diff, timeUnit) {
    // recursion bound condition
    if (timeUnit is chrono::nanoseconds) return getTimeElapsed(timeUnit, "ns");

    auto smallerTimeUnit = /* calculate smaller unit using current unit */
    if (timeUnit) return getTimeElapsed(timeUnit, ???, smallerTimeUnit, ???);
    else return prettyTimeElapsed(diff, smallerTimeUnit);
}
```

I was thinking of doing this:

```cpp
auto timeUnits = {chrono::hours(), chrono::minutes(), ..., chrono::nanoseconds()};
```

Then I could take the pointer (or even an index) to the time unit and pass it to the function.

The problem is that I don't know how to generalize these structs.

CLion highlights an error `Deduced conflicting types (duration<[...], ratio<3600, [...]>> vs duration<[...], ratio<60, [...]>>) for initializer list element type`

Comment: So in pseudocode, you want `std::cout << correctly_formatted(end - begin)`.  Am i right?

Comment: @L.F. Yes. Is `correctly_formatted` a function in a `chrono` library? If yes, that would solve the problem for me

Comment: Unfortunately, that's pseudocode ...  I posted that comment to make sure that I understood your question right.

Comment: Can you provide some input-output examples of the time formatting function?

Comment: @L.F. 

e.g the algorithm finds a solution after `1000000000` nanoseconds. 

I would like to see `Solution [...] found in 1 [s]`. 

If the algorithm works for `1234` nanoseconds:

 `... 1 [μs] 234 [ns]`

`123456789` nanoseconds => `123 [ms] 456 [μs]` or `123 [ms] 457 [μs]`

I don't care that much for a smaller unit precision (can be rounded or truncated)

Comment: Comments are supposed to be temporary.  Please [edit] the question to include the important information.

Comment: @L.F. I know that by default, `(end - begin)` will give me time in nanoseconds so I guess I could just extract `long long` value from the `diff = (end - begin)` and make a function that accepts `long long` and returns `string`

Comment: May I ask why you only want to print the first two lowest resolution units? If you're solution took 1 minute, 2 seconds, 345 milliseconds, and 678 microseconds, would you not want to convey all that information? This would be much easier to achieve, not to mention more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best general advice when working with `chrono` is to only escape the type-system (with the use of `.count()`) when you absolutely have to. This could be interfacing with C or some C++ library that doesn't understand chrono. Before C++ 20 this also means outputting to a stream.

If we keep ourselves inside the type system, we can get a lot of nice conversions that are **always** correct.

Let's correct the code in the question to reflect this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>

std::string getTimeElapsed(long time1, const std::string &unit1, long time2 = 0, const std::string &unit2 = "") {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << time1 << " [" << unit1 << "]";
    if (time2) s << " " << time2 << " [" << unit2 << "]";
    return s.str();
}

int main() {
    auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // algorithm goes here
    auto solution = "solution"; /* can be anything */
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto diff = end - begin;

    std::string timeElapsed{""};
    // Let's make the typing and reading easier for us but requires C++14
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(diff);
    auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(diff % 1h);
    if (hours != 0h) {
        // We need to escape the type system to call getTimeElapsed
        timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(hours.count(), "h", minutes.count(), "min");
    } else {
        auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(diff % 1min);
        if (minutes != 0min) {
            timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(minutes.count(), "min", seconds.count(), "s");
        } else {
            auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(diff % 1s);
            if (seconds != 0s) {
                timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(seconds.count(), "s", milliseconds.count(), "ms");
            } else {
                auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(diff % 1ms);
                if (milliseconds != 0ms) {
                    timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(milliseconds.count(), "ms", microseconds.count(), "μs");
                } else {
                    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff % 1us);
                    if (microseconds != 0us) {
                        timeElapsed = timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(microseconds.count(), "μs", nanoseconds.count(), "ns");
                    } else timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(nanoseconds.count(), "ns");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Solution [" << solution << "] found in " << timeElapsed << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now we are sticking to `chrono` for as long as we can. Calling `getTimeElapsed` is not `chrono` compatible, yet.

I'm not entirely satisfied, so let's support `duration`s in `getTimeElapsed` as well:

```cpp
template <typename Duration1, typename Duration2>
std::string getTimeElapsed(Duration1 time1, const std::string &unit1, Duration2 time2, const std::string &unit2) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << time1.count() << " [" << unit1 << "]";
    if (time2 != Duration2::zero()) s << " " << time2.count() << " [" << unit2 << "]";
    return s.str();
}

template <typename Duration1>
std::string getTimeElapsed(Duration1 time1, const std::string &unit1) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << time1.count() << " [" << unit1 << "]";
    return s.str();
}
```

We require two versions of `getTimeElapsed` since, in the last `else` we only use one time and unit argument pair, which means we cannot satisfy the `template` parameter requirements for two `Duration` types.
Now the code is looking much better (keeping only the relevant changes):

```cpp
...
    if (hours != 0h) {
        timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(hours, "h", minutes, "min");
    } else {
        auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(diff % 1min);
        if (minutes != 0min) {
            timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(minutes, "min", seconds, "s");
        } else {
            auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(diff % 1s);
            if (seconds != 0s) {
                timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(seconds, "s", milliseconds, "ms");
            } else {
                auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(diff % 1ms);
                if (milliseconds != 0ms) {
                    timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(milliseconds, "ms", microseconds, "μs");
                } else {
                    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff % 1us);
                    if (microseconds != 0us) {
                        timeElapsed = timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(microseconds, "μs", nanoseconds, "ns");
                    } else timeElapsed = getTimeElapsed(nanoseconds, "ns");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Great! However, we are still inviting users to send whatever they want to `getTimeElapsed` which, unless they happen to have a `.count()` member, will result in a compiler error.
Let's constrain our `template` just a little bit:

```cpp
template <typename Rep1, typename Ratio1, typename Rep2, typename Ratio2>
std::string getTimeElapsed(std::chrono::duration<Rep1, Ratio1> time1, const std::string &unit1, std::chrono::duration<Rep2, Ratio2>  time2, const std::string &unit2) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << time1.count() << " [" << unit1 << "]";
    if (time2 != time2.zero()) s << " " << time2.count() << " [" << unit2 << "]";
    return s.str();
}

template <typename Rep, typename Ratio>
std::string getTimeElapsed(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Ratio> time1, const std::string &unit1) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << time1.count() << " [" << unit1 << "]";
    return s.str();
}
```

We don't need to change the calling code for this one. I believe that this is sufficient to help you understand how to use `std::chrono::duration` in a more generic context, which whas a sub-question that you had.

Now we can start to tackle your question which I think (from reading the comments) is actually "How can I tidy up the nested `if` statements and print out only the first two, non-zero units."

This is not as simple as it would first appear. In my opinion, recursion is rarely the answer. Thinking of it as a loop over the types of unit is also over-engineering it and you would need to write some code to get the index of the current type from a tuple, increase it by one, then use that to index the same tuple to get the next unit with higher resolution. Then, when all that is said and done, you **still** need to know what unit to print to give the value its context. I would rather see the `getTimeElapsed` written as follows:

```cpp
std::string getTimeElapsed(std::chrono::nanoseconds elapsed, size_t maxUnits = 2)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::ostringstream formatted("");

    int usedUnits{};

    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(elapsed);
    if (hours != 0h)
    {
        formatted << hours.count() << " [h] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(elapsed % 1h);
    if (minutes != 0min)
    {
        formatted << minutes.count() << " [min] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(elapsed % 1min);
    if (seconds != 0min && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << seconds.count() << " [s] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed % 1s);
    if (milliseconds != 0ms && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << milliseconds.count() << " [ms] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed % 1ms);
    if (microseconds != 0us && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << microseconds.count() << " [us] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(elapsed % 1us);
    if (nanoseconds != 0us && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << nanoseconds.count() << " [us] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    return formatted.str();
}
```

Take the total elapsed time as `std::chrono::nanoseconds` (which you already have from `end - begin`) and pass it in to `getTimeElapsed`. We now do the same calculations as before to get the component units, but also keep track of how many units we have calculated. If `elapsed` is 1'000'000'000ns, then the result is "1 [s] "; if `elapsed` is 1'234'568ns, then the result is "1 [ms] 234 [us] ". There is trailing space, but I will leave that to you to fix.

This also means that we no longer require the `template`s we had refactored before, but I added them to show my thought process throughout this refactoring. The final program looks like:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string getTimeElapsed(std::chrono::nanoseconds elapsed, size_t maxUnits = 2)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::ostringstream formatted("");

    int usedUnits{};

    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(elapsed);
    if (hours != 0h)
    {
        formatted << hours.count() << " [h] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(elapsed % 1h);
    if (minutes != 0min)
    {
        formatted << minutes.count() << " [min] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(elapsed % 1min);
    if (seconds != 0min && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << seconds.count() << " [s] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed % 1s);
    if (milliseconds != 0ms && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << milliseconds.count() << " [ms] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed % 1ms);
    if (microseconds != 0us && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << microseconds.count() << " [us] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(elapsed % 1us);
    if (nanoseconds != 0us && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << nanoseconds.count() << " [us] ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    return formatted.str();
}

int main() {
    auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // algorithm goes here
    auto solution = "solution"; /* can be anything */
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto diff = end - begin;

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << "Solution [" << solution << "] found in " << getTimeElapsed(1'234'567ns) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to take this one step further and never need to escape the type system, then I would suggest looking in to  [Howard Hinnant's `date`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library. This library is the basis for the new `chrono` functionality in C++20 and brings string formatting to the table. Simply include `date.h` from the library in whatever way is appropriate for you and modify `getTimeElapsed` as follows:

```cpp
std::string getTimeElapsed(std::chrono::nanoseconds elapsed, size_t maxUnits = 2)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::ostringstream formatted("");

    int usedUnits{};

    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(elapsed);
    if (hours != 0h)
    {
        formatted << hours << " ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(elapsed % 1h);
    if (minutes != 0min)
    {
        formatted << minutes << " ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(elapsed % 1min);
    if (seconds != 0min && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << seconds << " ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed % 1s);
    if (milliseconds != 0ms && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << milliseconds << " ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed % 1ms);
    if (microseconds != 0us && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << microseconds << " ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(elapsed % 1us);
    if (nanoseconds != 0us && usedUnits != maxUnits)
    {
        formatted << nanoseconds << " ";
        ++usedUnits;
    }

    return formatted.str();
}
```

Using the same values as before, the results would now be: "1ms 234us " for 1'234'567ns.